# how to drag or drop multi uitableveiwcells on ios?

Tags: ios, uitableview, recorder

I want do drag a lot of selected cells and recorder them in my app.But I don't know how to do it.It seems apple just let u to drag one that what I have done it.
idea?

Answer (score 2):

If it is ok to require that the selected cells are contiguous, then you can cheat by replacing them with a single tall cell.

**EDIT:**
For noncontiguous, the lazy solution would be to let the user select any cells, then after they drag and drop one of them, just move all the other selected cells right below it.

You could experiment with `UITableView` and see if it will let you animate out the other selected cells (with `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`) as soon as dragging is detected (possibly with `UITableViewDelegate`'s `tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:`). You could also see if it will let you redraw/resize the cell when it begins dragging - then you could make it look like a z-layered stack or totem pole them into a tall cell while dragging.

Of course I'm assuming all the selected cells will share the same destination position. I can't wrap my head around noncontiguous sources to noncontiguous destinations in one drag-n-drop. If the user drags down 3 slots, does that mean you add 3 to the positions of all the selected cells? What if that takes a cell out of bounds? Even if you decided on some rules for odd cases like those and actually implemented this monstrosity, it could never be user friendly.

Comment: But the contiguous is just one state,it can't be the perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way out. You need to handle the animation and movement by yourself.
Maybe you can take a copy of the cells you want to move and show an animation of moving to the destination.
When animation stops change the datasource.

Comment: I have done move one cell with animation.But one question,how to copy the moving cell to the destination???